# Making a dictionary out of a text file:

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file like this :

```
matt=Lives in oakland
drey=lives in San Francisco
```

how can i make a dictionary like this

```
{matt:Lives in oakland,drey:lives in San Francisco}
```

I used this code:

```
d = {}
with open('hints.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:        
        name, residence = line.strip().split('=')
        d[name] = residence
```

It is giving me this error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Can you show your coding attempt at this and explain what is currently not working out for you?

Comment: Have you seen [configparser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)?

Comment: Also, your expected output is not a valid Python data structure. Do you mean: `{'matt': 'Lives in oakland', 'drey': 'lives in San Francisco'}`?

Comment: Seems like a simple `str.split("=")` should do the trick...

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Looks like there is a line in the file that doesn't contain a `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split on `'='` and then send it to `dict()`:

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
    d = dict(line.strip().split('=') for line in f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the lines, split them on `=`, and build a `dict` along the way:

```
d = {}
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:        
        name, residence = line.strip().split('=')
        d[name] = residence
```